# BOM is not exploded when called via BAPI_SALESORDER_CREATEFROMDAT2

Tags: abap, bapi, sap-erp

I'm attempting to create a sales order with a position that has a configurable material. Via the BAPI function `bapi_salesorder_createfromdat2` I can create the order and supply it with the values for the characteristics.

ABAP Code: http://pastebin.com/hM61c3Fq

When creating an order via VA01 and entering the configuration the order receives new positions from a bill of materials. However when created via the BAPI function the explosion doesn't happen unless I view the order via `va02` and look at the configuration.

[image: Opening order in VA02, viewing configuration, BOM explosion as result]

The customizing via transaction `vov7` shows the position type to configure and explode. Is it possible to have `bapi_salesorder_createfromdat2` also do this explosion to position lines or is there another function avaliable that can provide this functionality?

Answer (score 0):

It would seem, despite the overwheling amount of documentation that says it should work, I haven't been able to find a solution via the BAPI function. However, we eventually stumbled upon an SAP note 562124. After creating the function with `bapi_salesorder_createfromdat2` BAPI function `BAPI_SALESORDER_CHANGE` can be called. Afterwards the structure is exploded.

Comment: Extend your post to a full-featured answer so that all others can (re)use it.